# MVC complex Project and code - process flow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

IS there a service or third party product can help show me the code flow (start to end, including all function and class types) related to MVC 3&4 ?

I have a complex project and need to understand the underlaying framework process flow and functionality around that - any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will depend greatly on your project as the flow in such a beast can vary dramatically. However, if we are talking about the framework itself, then that of course is well defined and follows the pattern below:

- Receive first request for the application
- Perform routing
- Create MVC request handler
- Create controller
- Execute controller
- Invoke action
- Execute result

there are many examples of complex projects on codeplex (mvcstore for example), that will help you explore the implementation of the above.

Also, take a wander thro:

- http://downloads.academy.telerik.com/svn/school-academy/Meeting-24-ASP.NET-MVC/ASP.NET%20MVC%20Pipeline.pdf
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43153/Beginners-Guide-s-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-Part-1

I'll be honest, this stuff can be daunting at first but once you understand the pipeline, the project nuances all fit in far easier.

good luck